# Class Methods on Multi Threading Environment

Tags: java, multithreading, java-11

I'm creating a class with a method as below, which calls two methods inside `buildHttpPostRequest()` and `process()` in the same class.

```
public JSONObject request(final JSONObject authJson) {

            final HttpClient httpClient = HttpUtil.getHttpClient();
            final HttpPost httpPost = buildHttpPostRequest(authJson);
            final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            return process(response);
}
```

```
private HttpPost buildHttpPostRequest(final JSONObject json)  {

        final List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
        param.add("test");

        if (authJson.length() == 0) {
            param.add("test1");

        } else {
            param.add("test2");

        }
        final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param, AuthConstants.ENCODING_FORMAT.getValue()));
        return httpPost;
}
```

```
private JSONObject checkEDPGatewayStatusCode(final HttpResponse response){

// some switch case inside the method

return jsonObject;
}
```

i use JDK11. When it comes to multi threading environment, creating in `StampedLock` instance in `request()` and releasing in `process()` would be sufficient?

```
StampedLock stampedLock = new StampedLock();
```

any guidance and support would be appreciated since am new to multithreading programming model.

Comment: i found one thing that i need to use ```Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());``` in buildHttpPostRequest().

Comment: It doesn’t look like these methods use anything from the object they are invoked on. Without shared mutable state, there is no need to protect any state. And *no* especially not a locally used `ArrayList` that is never seen by any other thread.

Comment: thank you very much Holger, am just curious this method is invoked by REST API call, so ```ArrayList``` will not be a problem?

Comment: Since you are not trying to modify the list after you’ve passed it to the REST API, not even keeping a reference to it, whatever the REST implementation does with it is not your business anymore. Usually, the parameters are only read and concurrent reading is no problem at all.

Comment: Cool, thanks Holger!